# How can I have different CSS code for browsers that do not support border-radius`

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc

I would like to make use of border-radius and the different variations on my web pages. I'd also like to have alternate CSS for the browsers that don't support this. I am using MVC3.

Is there a simple way that I could have different CSS presented depending on if the browser does or does not support border-radius and just have ONE CSS file. In other words I would prefer to not have to have an additional CSS file to manage different variations of browser.

I read about BrowserCaps. Is anyone using this with MVC3 for CSS switching?

Answer (score 2):

Use the excellent jQuery round corner plugin.

http://jquery.malsup.com/corner/

It's supported in all browsers including IE. It draws corners in IE using nested divs (no images). It also has native border-radius rounding in browsers that support it (Opera 10.5+, Firefox, Safari, and Chrome). So in those browsers the plugin simply sets a css property instead.

### Here's How to use it

You need to include the jQuery and the Corner js script before `</body>`. Then write your jQuery like $('div, p').corner('10px'); and place before ''. So your html will look like the below code. Here i'm making round corners for all `div` and `p` tags. If you want to do it for specific id or class then you can do something like `$('#myid').corner();`

```
<body>
    <div class="x"></div>
    <p class="y"></p>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://github.com/malsup/corner/raw/master/jquery.corner.js?v2.11"></script>
    <script>$('div, p').corner();</script>
</body>
```

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/VLPpk/1

**UPDATE**

If you want a cross browser Solution using only CSS, then use the following

```
.curved {
  behavior: url("border-radius.htc");
  -moz-border-radius: 20px; /* Firefox */
  -webkit-border-radius: 20px; /* Safari and Chrome */
  -khtml-border-radius: 20px; /* Linux browsers */
  border-radius: 20px; /* Opera 10.50, IE and CSS3 */
}
```

Download the htc file from http://code.google.com/p/curved-corner to make this work in IE browsers. jQuery plugin mentioned above remains the easiest way to do this where you don't have to modify so many CSS properties everytime you want to issue a radius.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the suggestion but the pages that I serve I'd like to keep very lean a jquery free. I'm just looking to do some slightly different CSS and not add round corners. There are also other things I would like to style different for IE8 so I'm still looking for a solution.

Comment: I updated the answer with cross browser CSS properties to use for radius. jQuery remains the easiest way to go where you don't have to modify so many radius CSS properties everytime you want to make a radius.

Comment: Just wanted to share another solution that I've been using for a while: [http://css3pie.com/](http://css3pie.com/). Something about styling with javascript and unsupported css features gives me the willies, so I always prefer the .htc solution, especially since it only affects IE, while good browsers use their native rendering.

Answer (score 1):

Modernizr might be helpful for you. It would add either borderradius or no-borderradius to your markup using javascript and you can then style based on that:

http://www.modernizr.com/docs/#borderradius